# In codeigniter How i can check update?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
if($this->db->affected_rows()>0){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
```

but in that case, if user dose not changed before information that in db's Info, it does not update.

So always return 0;

I want check update's Successful or fail

How I can Check?

Comment: check like this if($this->db->affected_rows()!=-1 && $this->db->affected_rows()>=0){}

Comment: check the query using $this->db->last_query()

Comment: try this $this->db->affected_rows() >= 0

Comment: please check once query if $this->db->affected_rows() always return 0

Comment: making use of transaction is best see below answer @Polaris Nation

Answer (score 1):

Just use check like this

```
if($this->db->affected_rows()>=0){}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is use transaction mechanism of codeigniter as below:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();//begins your transaction
$data =<data> //data for upadating
$this->db->where('id', $id);//where condition
$this->db->update('table_name',$data);//update query

 if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)//checks transaction status
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();//if update fails rollback and  return false
       return FALSE;

    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();//if success commit transaction and returns true
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: `$this->db->trans_start(TRUE);` You can also test it by adding true https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#test-mode

Comment: yes `trans_begin` Runs Transactions Manually.`trans_start` runs transactions as a test mode.Both works fine.